# By using `SautinSoft.PdfFocus` dll while converting .docx file it shows some unwanted lines

Tags: c#, pdf, converters, docx

When I convert .pdf to .docx files using `SautinSoft.PdfFocus` dll it converts the files but on the last page it displays some unwanted data like `converted by PDF Focus.Net 6.1.1.30 The trial version can process only 300 paragraphs click to get......`

How can I remove that content while processing the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You purchase a license.

You're using a trial license.

Visit the [order page](http://www.sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-focus/order.php) to purchase a license to get rid of that message.

If you have already purchased a license then you need to download, install, and license the full version of the product as is described on the [Q&A page](http://www.sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-focus/order.php#Q1A):

> After processing of your order Avangate will automatically send to you email with link to download full version of product and your registration data (serial number, order ID, license type, name).

Comment: Is there any way to replace that unwanted data

Comment: You won't get an answer on this site on how to circumvent this. The correct way to get rid of this message is to use the full version, for which you have to pay. If you're not prepared to pay for the license, you either accept that the message is part of your document, as well as the limit of maximum of 300 paragraphs, or you find some other library without these limitations, or with a price you can accept.

Comment: Is there another way to convert rtf to .docx files without using interop dll and this `SautinSoft.PdfFocus dll`

Comment: Probably, some other library perhaps? I have no experience with any of them.